# What is the phonetic transcription of the name Jenna?

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, american-english

what is the IPA phonetic transcription of the female name Jenna? Is it ['dʒɛ nə], with stress on first syllable? I usually tend to use online dictionaries for pronunciation of words, but I couldn't find this one on any site.

Comment: You would have to supply an audio recording, plus samples of all of the other contrastive features of that dialect. There isn't a single transcription for all dialects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEPD-18 gives [ˈdʒen.ə], LPD-3 doesn't have this name. Naturalally, it depends on your dialect, especially with vowels.